# Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::updateCacheData()

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to clone a sheet and add it to a workbook, however, I am getting this error message:

```
Error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::updateCacheData()
File: C:\myProjects\PHP\Alfarsi\Source\Source2\app\Vendor\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php
Line: 106
```

the code snippet is:

```
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(COM_template);
        $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $my_copy=clone $activeSheet;
        $my_copy->setTitle('a copy');
        $objPHPExcel->addSheet($my_copy);
```

*Note: I am using phpexcel v1.7.9*

Comment: I believe this bug has already been fixed in the latest develop branch on [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: in the [changelog](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/changelog.txt) nothing is mentioned about updateCacheData. In addition, I am using some methods which are deprecated in 1.8.0, so I want to avoid the new version for now

Comment: There are no methods that are deprecated in the latest develop code that aren't already deprecated in 1.7.9, the codefixes in the develop branch are still part of the PHPExcel 1.x branch - the new version code for PHPExcel2 is completely separate

Comment: The fix in question is referenced in the changelog as `- Bugfix:   (MBaker)                            - Problem with cloning worksheets`

Comment: I am worried about line 111 in the changelog, since it says that this method may have been removed from the new version 1.8.0. I am using this method everywhere in my code (getCalculatedValue)

Comment: Take my word for it.... that method will only disappear with PHPExcel version 2.... I know the developer of the library personally, and he assures me that is the case... sadly for him, PHPExcel 1.x is not yet at end of life while so many people are still running PHP 5.2

Comment: I tried the latest updated classes and it is working! Thanks a lot